# Rmarkdown html add meta

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

We are trying to create a very simple webpage on corona virus statistics ([corona-stat.lt](https://corona-stat.lt/)). We basically knit Rmarkdown in Rstudio with .Rmd --> html (here the source [at GitHub](https://github.com/justasmundeikis/corona-stat-lt/blob/master/index.Rmd)). Does anybody know, if there is a way to define html meta, so that we could have

```
<meta property="og:url" content="corona-stat.lt" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Corona-Stat.lt" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justasmundeikis/corona-stat-lt/master/figures/corona-stat-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:type" content="page" />
```

from inside the `index.Rmd` file, but without destroying the html code of the `flatly theme`? I know, I could probably manually change the index.html file, but is too tedious to do every time we update something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [metathis](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/metathis/) package.

Here is a basic example according to the documentation:

````
    ```{r, echo=FALSE}

#install the library before calling it

library(metathis)

meta() %>%
  meta_description(
    "This book will teach you how to do data science with R..."
  ) %>% 
  meta_name("github-repo" = "hadley/r4ds") %>% 
  meta_viewport() %>% 
  meta_social(
    title = "R for Data Science",
    url = "https://r4ds.had.co.nz",
    image = "https://r4ds.had.co.nz/cover.png",
    image_alt = "The cover of the R4DS book",
    og_type = "book",
    og_author = c("Garrett Grolemund", "Hadley Wickham"),
    twitter_card_type = "summary",
    twitter_creator = "@hadley"
  )
```
````